# google nearby places api to display places types and places count

Tags: android, google-places-api

I want to display the places types first & places count while clicking on the types,i want to display the particular type only.please provide the solution for it.i am providing the screenshot my screen.every time category clicked i have to hit the  google url it will not good way.please suggest me simple way to use it.[image]

Comment: yes you are supposed to get the places from the server. You have to hit the url. You can cache the response if you don't want to hit te url evertytime

Comment: i am a newbie in android please provide any steps for caching process

Comment: make an effort first and post some code then someone will help

Comment: hi thank you i find the solution,if this data is stored in parcelable i can use across threads. Parcelable to facilitate high performance inter process communication.i followed this [link](http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/09/a-parcelable-tutorial-for-android.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple ...try this code:

```
StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    url.append("location=" + latLng.latitude + "," + latLng.longitude);
    url.append("&radius=5000");
    url.append("&types=" + "gas_station");
    url.append("&sensor=true");
    url.append("&key=your key");
```

here i used `gas_station` , you can use as per your need

use this api in each option and just change `&types=""` according to your options.

for supported types you have to refer [this link](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)